# @Transactional(readonly=true) behavior with hibernate session flush

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

We have class like below

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class AService {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Autowired
  private ARepository arepo;

  public void saveA(A a) {
    arepo.save(a);
  }

  public void saveandFlushA(A a) {
    arepo.save(a);
    entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).flush();
  }
}
```

We are using **postgres + jpa-hibernate + spring transaction management**, when we call the **save(a)** method its not causing a save commit, which is normal behavior since my transaction is set to readonly=true but when i call **saveandFlushA(a)** its causing insert statement fired and get committed but i'm expecting it to be not committed.

Spring Transaction doc says **readOnly** flag sets **Read/write vs. read-only transaction**

I did not understand why the data gets committed even its a readonly transaction ?  any insight would be greatly welcomed.